# Do not allow 0 when creating column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a table in SQL Server and I have a column of `decimal` type that should not receive the value 0, how could I do that?

```
CREATE TABLE Producto
(
    Idproducto [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL 
        DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR Idprod),
    Nombre [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    Precio_Unitario DECIMAL (18,2) 
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CHECK` constraint. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Producto
(
    Idproducto int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Nombre varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Precio_Unitario DECIMAL(18, 2),
    CONSTRAINT chk1 CHECK (Precio_Unitario <> 0)
);
```

Typical inserts will work well:

```
INSERT INTO Producto (Idproducto, Nombre, Precio_Unitario) 
VALUES (1, 'A', 2);

INSERT INTO Producto (Idproducto, Nombre, Precio_Unitario) 
VALUES (2, 'B', NULL);
```

But if you try:

```
INSERT INTO Producto (Idproducto, Nombre, Precio_Unitario) 
VALUES (3, 'C', 0);
```

You'll get an error:

> Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk1". The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_914c4e0be5e144138dc870cf3d5a6ced", table "dbo.Producto", column 'Precio_Unitario'.
>
> Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 1
> The statement has been terminated.

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=610bd24302f06ef0b50f775b9551aebb).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a check constraint, that will force all values in that column to be null or different from zero

```
CREATE TABLE #Producto
(
    Idproducto [int]  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR Idprod),
    Nombre [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    Precio_Unitario DECIMAL  (18,2),
    constraint chk_Precio_Unitario check (Precio_Unitario <> 0) 
)
```

Comment: `CHECK` ignores nulls anyway

Comment: @Charlieface I was not aware of that, I always put that extra check on null. I have edited my answer

Comment: @Charlieface CHECK does NOT ignore nulls. The logic of comparing a value to zero will not return TRUE if the value is NULL.

Comment: @SMor It certainly does https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69c9b59bb66e97c74a253410779f2de3 this is fully documented see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations-of-check-constraints. It's looking for failing values which result in `FALSE` not `UNKNOWN`